# Merge the changes made in the master while keeping the changes made locally in git

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase, git-stash

I have cloned a particular repo. Suppose it is at state A. I have made some changes to it locally, suppose it is  A -> B.  But some changes have already been updated in the master branch of repo, suppose it is A->C. 
Now, I need to update my local repo and then merge my changes to it. That is, it should be A-> C-> B . How do I do this ? 
After googling a lot, I found out it can done using

```
git stash
```

Some blogs said that even

```
git rebase
```

can be used to do it. Can you please help with the command sequence that I need to follow? (for merging conflicts I am using kDiff3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't ready to commit your changes

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

If you are ready to commit your changes, then commit then. Then you can just

```
git pull --rebase
```

If you have some committed changes, and some changes you're not ready to commit, you can combine these:

```
git stash
git pull --rebase
git stash pop
```